# How to customize internal server error popup?

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-3

i want to replace the internal server error popup with forwarding the user to an error page, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your web.xml put this context params:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.connectionLostRedirectURI</param-name>
  <param-value>connectionLost.iface</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI</param-name>
  <param-value>connectionLost.iface</param-value>
</context-param>
```